# If $r\in(0,1)$ is rational and $m$ is a positive integer, then $[rm]+[(1-r)m]=m-1$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the integral part

Tags: arithmetic

Let $[\cdot]$ denote the integral part of a real number, that is the only integer $a$ satisfying

$a \leq x < a+1$.

Let $0<r<1$ be a rational number and $m \geq 0$ a positive integer.

How do you prove that the following equality?

$[rm]+[(1-r)m]=m-1$

This should be completely elementary but I don't manage!!

Comment: It's corrected now

Answer (score 2):

The claimed formula is incorrect.  If $r=1/2$ and $m=2$ then the two integer parts sum to $m$ rather than $m-1$.

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting. Which is the correct formula then?

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming at here, but at any rate of either of the numbers $rm$ and $(1-r)m$ is not an integer, then the sum will be $m-1$ as stated.  Therefore one needs to add a condition to ensure that one of them is not an integer.  For example, if you assume that $r$ is irrational instead of rational, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be true always.  Let $r=\frac 12, m=4$, then $[rm]+[(1-r)m]=4\neq m-1$.  But this gives a hint:  if $rm$ is integral, we have $[rm]+[(1-r)m]=rm+m-rm=m$, while if $rm$ is not integral we have $rm-[rm]+\{rm\}$ and $[rm]+[(1-r)m]=[rm]+[m-[rm]-\{rm\}]=[rm]+m-[rm]-1$  So the formula is correct for $rm$ non-integral, and the $-1$ should be removed for $rm$ integral.